# Can't open Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I started porting my app to Windows 10 Universal App today, started as a blank project. However I can't open the Package.appxmanifest file in Visual Studio, even when I right-click and select View Code (F7). It says "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information." Any solution for this?

Comment: Hi Nhan,

More info will be needed to fix this issue. Can you tell me what behavior you are seeing when you trying viewing the package.appxmanifest in the code editor? Are you running on Windows 10 or another OS? A workaround is to find the file in file explorer and open it in notepad to make your edits. Perhaps getting a schematically correct package.appxmanifest for Windows 10 will resolve the issue.

Also, how are you trying to update your app? Are you manually changing all of the project properties/manifest properties or did you create a new Windows 10 project and copied code?

Comment: It says "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.". I started the project blank, copy nothing from my previous one. And of course, I'm running Windows 10 as it's required to develop Universal App.

Comment: So you did file -> New project and created a Universal Windows app and can't open the manifest file? Try a repair on Visual Studio. Also, you can do Windows 10 app development on Windows 8.1, or Windows 7 (you just don't get all the features).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the Apache Cordova Tools Package.

Comment: I had the same error and I can confirm that removing the Apache Cordova Tools fixed the issue.

Comment: Your solution worked for me and I want to add a bit more details: 1. Trying to open the manifest from Solution Explorer does show the error, but not the cause. 2. View Code does not work for the manifest. 3. Opening the menu in VS, choosing Project=>Store=>Edit App Manifest does show the issue with the Apache Cordova Tools Package

Comment: That will fix it, but it's unnecessary. Please see my solution below - it will work for you.

Answer (score 5):

You are hitting by a known bug that we have fixed it for new installs. However, you could hit it if you installed the tools for universal apps within a specific period of time.

The steps outlined here will work for you: [Visual Studio 2015 RTM - Lost JavaScript support after update TypeSript Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888115/visual-studio-2015-rtm-lost-javascript-support-after-update-typesript-tools)

If the “Universal Windows App Development Tools” are still installed:

1.Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2105, click Change.
2.In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
3.Deselect the feature “Universal Windows App Development Tools”
4.Select “Universal Windows App Development Tools” again, and click Update.

If you have already uninstalled the “Universal Windows App Development Tools”:

- Reinstall “Universal Windows App Development Tools”
- Or, take the following steps to reinstall the JavaScript project system and language service:

  1.Download the installer for your edition of Visual Studio, e.g., vs_community.exe.

  2.Open a CMD window, and run the following command: vs_community.exe /modify /installselectableitems JavaScript_Hidden /passive

3.Change directories to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

4.Run the following commands

- devenv /updateconfiguration
- devenv /clearcache

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Extension and Updates > Update Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP.
This works for me.