# Can't loaded Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I use Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10. I create universal app for Windows 8.1. I need to open the file Package.appxmanifest (for Windows Phone 8.1). I can only see message - "loaded", but manifest editor is not loaded. If I created app for Windows 10 - manifest file is opened. I read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729255/cant-open-package-appxmanifest-in-visual-studio-2015). I try reinstall “Universal Windows App Development Tools” and install KB3073097 update, but it did not help.

Comment: what happens when you right click on the appxmanifest and click view designer?

Comment: In Visual Studio opened  empty appxmanifest with message - "loaded".

Comment: Have you tried to repair or reinstall the VS? And a screenshot may help others to understand this better.

Answer (score -1):

This is issue is completed.  I  installed the service pack 1 for visual studio 2015.