# Can't open Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, packaging, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem while opening the freshly created `Package.appxmanifest` by **Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 community** (with a new project `Windows Application Packaging Project` for Windows 10) on Windows 7.
I have an error message in a popup : `Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`.
There is a message in the bottom left corner : `This item does not support previewing`

I read a lot of already answered questions without success, like:

- [Can't open Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729255/cant-open-package-appxmanifest-in-visual-studio-2015)
- [Can't open Package.appxmanifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377005/cant-open-package-appxmanifest)
- [Can't loaded Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824614/cant-loaded-package-appxmanifest-in-visual-studio-2015)

And I try to :

- Reinstall Visual Studio 2019 Community
- Reinstall the extension.
- Do `devenv /updateconfiguration` and `devenv /clearcache`
- Open `Package.appxmanifest` with `View Code (F7)` or `View Designer (Shift+F7)`. Nothing happens.
- Click `Edit your package in a designer` on the overview of the project. After a long loading nothing happens.
- Use this extension : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ClearMEFComponentCache

.. without success either ...

After activating logs (`devenv /Log mylog`), I found these errors :

```
  <entry>
    <record>380</record>
    <time>2019/06/19 08:40:03.958</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>392</record>
    <time>2019/06/19 08:40:04.308</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l&apos;assembly &apos;Microsoft.Lync.Model, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c&apos; ou une de ses d&#x00E9;pendances. Le fichier sp&#x00E9;cifi&#x00E9; est introuvable.</description>
    <path>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\codesense\framework\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Client.Common.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>393</record>
    <time>2019/06/19 08:40:04.314</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l&apos;assembly &apos;Microsoft.WebTools.Languages.Json, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; ou une de ses d&#x00E9;pendances. Le fichier sp&#x00E9;cifi&#x00E9; est introuvable.</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\common7\ide\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>394</record>
    <time>2019/06/19 08:40:04.314</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l&apos;assembly &apos;Microsoft.WebTools.Languages.Json, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; ou une de ses d&#x00E9;pendances. Le fichier sp&#x00E9;cifi&#x00E9; est introuvable.</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\OPENFOLDER\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.VSIntegration.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>395</record>
    <time>2019/06/19 08:40:04.319</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l&apos;assembly &apos;Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeScript.EditorFeatures, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; ou une de ses d&#x00E9;pendances. Le fichier sp&#x00E9;cifi&#x00E9; est introuvable.</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\INTELLICODE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliCode.TypeScript.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>396</record>
    <time>2019/06/19 08:40:04.324</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
    <description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l&apos;assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; ou une de ses d&#x00E9;pendances. Le fichier sp&#x00E9;cifi&#x00E9; est introuvable.</description>
    <path>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\vc\languageserver\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.LanguageServer.dll</path>
  </entry>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Is UWP even supported on Windows 7?

Comment: I am afraid that it could be the cause of the error ...