# Receiving DEP6701 error when deploying to Hololens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, hololens-emulator

I wanted to run the Hololens sample of Vuforia (https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples#downloadModal --> Digital Eyewear).

I opened the package in Unity. To run it on the Hololens I performed the steps starting with Chapter 4 in the Hololens100 tutorial (https://developer.microsoft.com/de-DE/windows/holographic/holograms_100).

The build runs smoothly. However, if I try to deploy to the Hololens via USB or to the Hololens emulator I get error code DEP6701 (a type in the assembly could not be loaded).

Any ideas how to resolve this problem? I could not find any helpful information online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue with the standalone SDK I used (since I already had VS installed without Windows Universal Support).

I noticed that I had the same problem as [Can't open Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729255/cant-open-package-appxmanifest-in-visual-studio-2015). However, I did not have the Apache Cordova Tools installed, therefore the fix could not be applied.

What I did was the following:

1. Removed all SDKs I manually installed for the Hololens
2. Went to program and features --> Visual Studio 2015 --> Change and chose to install the Windows Universal Support with Tools etc.

That way my problem was resolved, so somehow the standalone SDK was yielding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy to Hololens device you have to select the x86 platform (instead of ARM) in the Visual Studio.

[image: Solution platform and target]

You also have to enable developer mode in the hololens developer settings. 
I prefer to deploy through wifi connection. In this case you have to:

- get the devide IP address (network settings -> advanced)
- go to project debug properties
- set the "Remote Machine" target device
- set the IP in the remote machine name

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already had that part right. But finally figured it out.