# Can't open Package.appxmanifest

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10-universal

When I create universal app and try to open Package.appxmanifest, doesn't work and It says "**Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information**." so any solution for this? and I'm using VS 2015

Comment: Please refer the [following question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729255/cant-open-package-appxmanifest-in-visual-studio-2015), it seems it throws the same error message. If it is not same issue to your problem, please tell us more detail about it.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT It's the same problem but I tried this solution but it didn't work so I tried another solution that repair VS from Programs and features and It did work. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to repair Visual Studio, it should fix the problem. There is likely a corrupted file preventing you from opening the package.appxmanifest.